# How to set pin domain(current or voltage) of UR robot with ur_msgs

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am currently working with a UR10 robot and i want to set the pin mode or domain as it is called to voltage instead of current for the analog output pins. In the [ur_msgs/Analog](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/ur_msgs/html/msg/Analog.html) documentation you can see that the Analog message has a pin and a domain which sets the pin mode to either voltage or current. This is not included in the [ur_msgs/setIO service](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/ur_msgs/html/srv/SetIO.html) of the [Universal_robot_driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver) far as i could see. Am i correct in this or am i not looking at it correctly? If this is not implemented, would it be a good idea to write a program to sets up a temporary socket connetion to the UR robot to force the pin mode/domain to voltage? Would ROS reset this when i would write a value to that pin with the ur_msgs/setIO service?

p.s. i am only talking about the Analog outputs of the UR10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343914/how-to-set-pin-domain(current-or-voltage)-of-ur-robot-with-ur_msgs/) by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment this does not seem to be implemented, but the pin domain can be set with the `ur_hardware_interface/script_command` topic. Example code:

```
// include
from std_msgs.msg import String 

// the function 
def apply_vacuum(self):
rospy.init_node("apply_vacum_node") 
publisher1 = rospy.Publisher('/ur_hardware_interface/script_command', String, queue_size=2)

try:
   // first 1 is the pin number and second number is the state of the pin 
    message = "sec MyProgram():" + "\n" + "set_standard_digital_out(1,1)" + "\n" + "end " + "\n"
    publisher1.publish(message)  
except rospy.ServiceException, e:
    print "Something went wrong: %s"%e
```

this will work but make sure you read the [scripting manual](https://www.universal-robots.com/download/?option=15649#section15646) for the functions that you can use in this format. make sure that you input the correct information. The format i used can be seen [here](https://www.universal-robots.com/how-tos-and-faqs/how-to/ur-how-tos/secondary-program-17257/).

you only need to the use the required function for the pin domain that you can find in the mentioned scripting manual in said post.

---

Originally posted by [stefvanlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40682/stefvanlierop/) with karma: 37 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-26**:
As this question is the one in which you actually asked about this, I thought it would be best to duplicate your answer from the question you linked here.